# Android: How to use fragments to completely change a view

Tags: android

My app has a custom segmented control(got it from internet - its really a radio group) and under it a listview. When a user clicks on a row in the list view, a fragment is attached to the activity that displays a different listview. This new listview seems to replace the old one. The problem is that the segmented control is still there, whereas I would like the whole view to be the new list view. Knowing that fragments are embedded in the view group, I thought progammatically removing the segmented control would work, but it didn't, the control just becomes empty space.

It's important that the app works the way I described. I could explain in detail why this is so, if needed.

Any tips? Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you removing your segmented control and inserting the fragment? It would be helpful to see both your Java code and XML layout.